# How to use console.timeStamp in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, console, timestamp, firebug

I try to use `console.timeStamp` in firebug, it works:

```
console.timeStamp()
12:16:26.188
```

but this does't work in chrome, it show `undefined`

how can I use it?

Comment: I also didn't understand how to use it. Instead I use `console.time('timerName')` to start a timer. `console.timeLog('timerName')` to log the time passed. And `console.timeEnd('timerName')` to stop the timer

Answer (score 4):

The console.timeStamp function in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoletimestamplabel) differs greatly from the one in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.timeStamp.28name.29). Chrome uses it to add an event to the [Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#marking_the_timeline) during a recording session whereas Firebug just creates a log in the console.

So for using timeStamp in chrome one has to start recording a Timeline session under the Timeline tab and the events then appear on the Timeline.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the console.timeStampe() in Firebug doesn't only create a log within the Console panel, but it also creates a mark (vertical line) in the Net panel's time line.
See more: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-1-8-console-timestamp/

Honza

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, write some code that calls `console.timeStamp()`:

```
function test4(foo) {
  console.timeStamp('Hello world!');
}
```

Then, open DevTools, go to Performance tab, and click Record (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>), execute your code, and stop the recording. You will see this events under the **Main** section:

[image: DevTools Performance Main section shows console.timeStamp event]

And you can use the Event Log section to search for instances of your `console.timeStamp()` events:

[image: DevTools Event Log section; search for console.timeStamp event]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, but performance.mark with performance.measure does. https://www.debugbear.com/blog/custom-front-end-performance-metrics